# Images in Formula

Tags: formula, developer

I want to set up formula that will show same image multiple times. 
For example if i have a field Lead_Quality =10 should give one star. If i have Lead_Quality = 30 should give 2 same stars. 
This is the code that I've done till now.

```
OR( Lead_Quality__c  = 10, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "*", 16, 16),
    Lead_Quality__c  = 30, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "*", 16, 16), 
                            IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "*", 16, 16))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
IF( Base_Price__c  >= 10, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "", 16, 16)+
IF(Base_Price__c >=30, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "", 16, 16)+
IF(Base_Price__c >=50, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "", 16, 16)
,"")
,"")
,"")
```

Comment: Not functional trying to combine both answers.

Comment: this will work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF( Lead_Quality__c >=30, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "" ,16, 16)+IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "" ,16, 16), 
IF(Lead_Quality__c >=10, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01520000002XTrg", "" ,16, 16),""))
```

Comment: Both are not functional. I am trying to work on the second comment from Snehaken and hoping I can figure it out.